# Is there a tool to make all classes package protected and final if possible?

Tags: java, ide, module

Background: I notice that in many projects almost all classes in the internal code are public and not final, even if they don't need to be. However, it seems sensible to me to make this decision not by default, but only make classes public if they are actually meant to be used from other parts of the system. Having package protected classes is an easy mechanism to enforce boundaries between modules, and serves as a documentation on the intended use of a class.

If there was a (preferrably free :-) tool to protect all classes that can be protected without breaking the program, and maybe make everything final that has no subclasses, that would be a good starting point to start a conscious use of protection mechanisms. (Of course you need to tweak things afterwards.) Do you know such tool?

Caveat: I am aware that there are better modularization mechanisms like OSGI and the planned superpackages and so forth. But in many current projects this is not an option, and using the plain old Java mechanisms is something you can easily do. Also, this works only if you have shared code ownership (such that everybody can change things back to public as needed) and if you are developing an endproduct, not a library for use by others. I am also not too sure about the benefits of making things final - this prevents AOP and mocking.

**CLARIFICATION**: As I said, I am not talking about libraries that are thrown over the fence to someone who can't change it, but about internal code of medium sized projects where everybody is encouraged to change and refactor everything as needed. When I am talking about package protected or final think of it as "protected until someone feels a compelling need to lift those restrictions". If someone feels the need to lift the restrictions set by the tool, he is welcome to do so.

Comment: How would such a tool know which classes are meant to be public and which are meant to be package-private? The "meant to be" part is only in the head of the programmer, a tool can't know that.

Comment: What are you trying to protect? Why did you make the classes you dont want public, public in the first place? Anyway, you should take look at ProGuard.

Comment: @SkPhilipp Not I made the classes public but other developers who did not think too much about structuring the application well. I am trying to make things more comprehensible, not obfuscating it. :-)

Comment: @Jesper I was talking about "have to be" not "meant to be" - and a tool can often judge that from the compile errors that would be created by reducing visibility, and maybe XML configurations that require public classes. Of course, you will have to tweak the result, but it might be better than the original state.

Comment: Making everything final is a hilarious idea from the OOP perspective. Also in java you usually use public classes then only use protected when you really really don't want to allow access to the class outside the package. With public classes you not share data so that's not a problem. (If you design your application properly)

Comment: @LakatosGyula: I don't agree. If everything is public, the overall API/application quickly becomes bloated. Reducing visibility is a very good thing to make code understandable, even if "publicness" isn't a *problem* by itself. Think about context-based auto-completion in an IDE. I don't want 500'000 classes to choose from... Also, there are a lot of debates about whether Java should've made `final` the default and `overridable` an option... But that's more of a matter of taste.

Comment: Kind of like the opposite of http://steve-yegge.blogspot.com/2010/07/wikileaks-to-leak-5000-open-source-java.html ?

Comment: @Lukas Eder You can write code that looks fancy in the IDE or being more reusable. (I agre on the IDE part, but the IDE shouldn't be the main focus.) Also if something is not overideable in an API, but you want some special function you need to use hacks/workarounds or not use the API at all. Well it's a matter of taste, but I use override enough to knw how much pain does a final method can cause to you. (Had a very hard time working 2 years ago with the GWT framework from gogle. It was soo badly designed, filled with final methods what shouldnt be final. Fortunately they refactored it since.)

Comment: @LakatosGyula `final` methods and classes are very useful. For instance, calling non-final methods from a constructor may create problems in the future (as described by Joshua Bloch in [Effective Java](http://www.amazon.com/Effective-Java-2nd-Joshua-Bloch/dp/0321356683). Being more reusable doesn't mean everything has to be public and non-final.

Comment: For everybody: see my clarification. @artbristol No, I do mostly agree with Steve Yegge on that; I am just talking about different things.

Comment: @hstoerr I was kidding around - I actually think such a tool that you propose would be very interesting (and I've voted you up and starred your question)

Answer (score 2):

Even if there was such a tool, (there isn't), a good programmer wouldn't use it... access specification is a design issue best understood and settled by the programmer himself. Think about it... you make a program and run the tool and get everything sorted (Assuming the tool is super-intelligent in the first place to actually understand your program).. then you decide to modify it... extend some classes, etc.. and you end up extending final classes and making objects of private classes.. (and these are few of the many problems you'll face)...

Thing is.. when the tool does its job, you would no longer even understand your own program.

Bottomline.. stop looking for tools to solve your design issues.. (its like asking for tools that will automatically debug your program)

Comment: I agree that making these design choices when writing the code is by far the best way to do it. But I was thinking about a situation where you inherit a code base of some thousands of classes where the programmers did not care too much about module structure. In such a case such a tool might help to get started with some more sensible structuring.  By the way: thanks, but saying the question is stupid is rather a comment but an answer. :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can have a look at [ATL](http://www.eclipse.org/atl/) from Eclipse. Although ATL is used to create model to model transformations between different kinds of models, there is no restriction that source and target model are not of the same type. You could create a transformation from Java to Java that makes your current classes protected or final. [MoDisco](http://www.eclipse.org/MoDisco/) is a toolset of Eclipse makes use of that, just if you want to see examples.